# Element Height based on percentage

Tags: html, css

So I've been experimenting with divs, trying to get the hang of overall page layouts. I put 1px borders on all of them so I could see how my css affects them. I'm just a little confused. I understand that setting any property to a percentage makes that property calculate based on the size of its container. (If I'm mistaken, correct me. I'm still learning all of this.)

But in terms of div height, I thought setting it to a percentage (where there is no container) leaves the height dependent on content, as you had never specified a height. However, I set a div height to 100% and it seems to have a predetermined height. I'll post the code.

HTML
Ignore the script links. Once I got a good grasp on layout stuff, I was gonna move on to Javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripttwo.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styletwo.css"/>
    <title>Messing With Div's</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id=one></div>
<div id=two></div>
<div id=three>
    <div id=four></div>
    <div id=five></div>
    <div id=six></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body
    {margin:0px;}

div
    {border:1px solid black;
    box-sizing:border-box}

#one
    {width:96%;
    height:100px;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:30px}

#two
    {width:40%;
    height:500px;
    margin-left:2%;
    margin-top:2%;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom:30px}

#three
    {width:54%;
    margin-top:2%;
    margin-right:2%;
    display:inline-block;
    float:right}

#four
    {width:90%;
    height:20%;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:10%;
    border:1px solid red;
    display:static}

#five
    {width:90%;
    height:20%;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:10%;
    border:1px solid red;
    display:static}

#six
    {width:90%;
    height:20%;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:10%;
    margin-bottom:10%;
    border:1px solid red;
    display:static}
```

Answer (score 1):

`#one` and `#two` will obviously have a pre-determined height of 100px and 500px respectively.

`#three` doesn't have any height at first, because there is nothing in it and a height isn't set in the css or html. However, when you add the three divs below into it, it will have a height of 2px + the margin-top + margin - bottom of those three divs inside of it...

`#four, #five, and #six` should only have a height of 2px each. Since there is nothing in them and their height is 20% of #three(which is 0) so the 20% is 0. The border adds 1px to each side of the div, so the top and bottom adds to height. So like I said, each would have a visable height of 2px.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It has to do with HTML versions. I changed "!doctype" to "!doctype html", and it fixed it. Whatever version it was using before obviously had the divs "bypassing" their container because it didn't have a height set for it. The next container up with a height defined was body, its height being the window height. When I added "html", I got the same result as per jsfiddle.

EDIT:The reason I figured out that it was "bypassing" the container, is because once I defined a specific height for #three, then the others sized themselves correctly.

EDIT 2: Now, a div I put outside of #three (also set to 20%), does the same as the ones inside of #three (just a line). So I guess the height of the "body" is undefined where whatever version it was using before had it set to window height?

Answer (score 0):

You specified margins in div `#four`, `#five` and `#six` so the height is based on your content, exactly the `margin` of 10% to a top and 10% based on the **container width**.

In detail: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp

> % Specifies a margin in percent of the width of the containing element

Look here, your layout without a `margin`: http://jsfiddle.net/23HcY/

```
#four
{
  width:90%;
  height:20%;
  margin:auto;
  margin-top:0%;
  border:1px solid red;
  display:static
}

#five
{
  width:90%;
  height:20%;
  margin:auto;
  margin-top:0%;
  border:1px solid red;
  display:static
}

#six
{
  width:90%;
  height:20%;
  margin:auto;
  margin-top:0%;
  margin-bottom:0%;
  border:1px solid red;
  display:static
}
```

Comment: What you posted is exactly how I expected it should look. But #four-#six all have a perceivable height of almost 100px. It does this in both Chrome and Safari. Any ideas why? I wish I could upload a photo of what I'm seeing here.

Comment: So you see your div's local in a other way then in my posted jsfiddle link? Try to reload (cmd-r, strg-r) or/and delete the cashed data for your site.

Comment: I refreshed and got the same issue. I haven't tried the to clear cashed data, yet. But in fiddling around a little before I read this comment, I took the last three divs out of #three and they retained their height. So it looks as if, even when they're in the container #three, that they're calculating height based on the size of the window. Does that sound right to you?

Comment: Clearing the cache didn't do anything.

Comment: If i do so, i get this behavior http://jsfiddle.net/aYcm6/ (in Chrome, Safari and Firefox)  like you wished, are you sure to set all margins to zero?

Comment: I get the same thing on jsfiddle. I'm gonna try completely restarting my browser. And if that doesn't work, the entire computer.

Comment: By the same thing, I mean the same thing as you. It looks as it should. But my local results are still as they were, uncooperative. lol

Comment: Neither a browser nor computer restart fixed it. I have no idea what's going on. I'm 99% sure that these heights (judging visually by their sizes) are being calculated based on window size.

Comment: You can try to delete all margin settings from #4,5,6 - but I think this will only effect the centering of your three divs. But it will eliminate the chance you forgot a few margins.

Comment: "I wish I could upload a photo of what I'm seeing here", good plan I think.  Get Irfanview or something like it and learn how to capture the screen and submit it.  I think as a programmer it's an important tool that should be in your kit.